# Matlab, how to see the source code of the function mean()?

Tags: matlab

I know some built-in functions cannot be accessed in Matlab, but is that true for all functions even simple ones?

Can I see somewhere the source code of the predefined function mean(), and in case of complex numbers z^5 all 5 solutions for the complex number (because Matlab displays just one solution) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Type "edit mean" into the command window.